# Hide item number without removing numbering from list

Tags: lists, itemize, enumitem

What I would like to do is removing the item number from an `enumerate` list like the one below

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \theenumi
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

without changing the `\theenumi` counter. Using `\item[]` doesn't work because it resets the item counter at 0. Same problem with using `\label = {}` as an environment option. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Renew `\labelenumi` like this:

```
\renewcommand\labelenumi{}
```

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
%\usepackage[italian]{babel}
%\usepackage{enumitem}
\renewcommand\labelenumi{}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
   \item \theenumi
   \item next \theenumi
   \item next \theenumi
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]